# didReceiveRemoteNotification method is not Calling when Notification is Coming

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ios11

I am not understanding why my code is not Working.

**my code is**:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

{

    print("User Info = ",userInfo)

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "reloadChatTableView"), object: nil)

    GlobalConstant.notificationDict = userInfo

    let notificationDictionary: NSDictionary = GlobalConstant.notificationDict?["aps"] as! NSDictionary

    let type: String = Global.getStringValue(notificationDictionary.value(forKey: "type") as AnyObject)

    //   application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = application.applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.noData)

var aps: [AnyHashable: Any] = userInfo["aps"] as! [AnyHashable : Any]

        //content.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "tone.mp3")

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 1, repeats: false)

        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timerDone", content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: nil
}
```

Comment: Hi Kumar! Could you please format the code? It is not clear this way

Comment: Do you check your APNs works well? For example, you could try to change badge number.

Comment: unfortunately , I am formatting but its not happening.

Comment: Try with https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher and add a break point in your app and check whether it works or not.

Comment: Please update your question with a description of the behavior you are seeing, the behavior you expect, and the push notification payload.